# Prime $p$ for $\frac{p+7}{2}, \frac{p^2+7}{2}$ are both perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $p$ is prime number such that $\frac{p+7}{2}, \frac{p^2+7}{2}$ are both perfect squares.

I know $p=11$ is only solution but don't know how to do it. I try $\frac{p+7}{2}=a^2$ and $\frac{p^2+7}{2}=b^2$ then $(2a^2-7)^2+7=2b^2$ but can't solve it. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Where did you come up with this question? This problem needs context, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From
$$ \frac{p+7}{2}=a^2, \frac{p^2+7}{2}=b^2 $$
one has
$$ (p-1)p=2(b-a)(b+a).\tag1 $$
Clearly $a<p$ since otherwise one would have
$$ \frac{p+7}{2}\ge p^2 $$
which does not hold for $p\ge3$. Similarly $b<p$. So
$$a+b<2p. \tag2$$
From(1), one has
$$ p|(b+a). \tag3$$
From (1), (2)and (3), one has
$$ b+a=p, 2(b-a)=p-1 $$
which gives
$$ a=\frac{p+1}{4}, b=\frac{3p-1}4. $$
Putting them to $(2a^2-7)^2+7=2b^2$, one has, after simplifying
$$ (p-11)(p+5)(p^2+10p-63)=0. \tag4$$
So $p=11$.

Update: John Omielan suggested the following way to avoid the third term in (4). Note
$$ p^2=(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab=\frac{p+7}{2}+\frac{p^2+7}{2}+\frac{(p+1)(3p-1)}8$$
and hence, after simplification
$$ p^2-6p-55=0. $$
So $p=11$.

Comment: From your equation, we can get that $p \mid b + a$, so $b + a = kp$ and $p - 1 = 2k(b - a)$ for some integer $k \ge 1$. However, how have you determined that $k = 1$ is the only possible value? Also, note the final result should be $p = 11$, not $p = 5$.

Comment: I am trying to fix it.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, I think now it is ok.

Comment: Yes, you have now shown that $k = 1$. Good work. However, you still have $p = 5$ showing as being the final answer. Also, note there's a different, I believe somewhat simpler way, to get the result. Squaring $b + a = p$ gives $b^2 + 2ab + a^2 = p^2$. Using $b^2 = \frac{p^2+7}{2}$, $a^2 = \frac{p + 7}{2}$, and the results for $a$ and $b$ you got giving $2ab = \frac{(p+1)(3p-1)}{8}$, then substituting, multiplying both sides by $8$ and simplifying the equation results in $p^2 - 6p - 55 = 0 \;\;\to\;\; (p - 11)(p + 5) = 0$, i.e., this avoids your third quadratic term.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, Good comments. Thanks a lot.